# To understand Task and scheduling better

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, scheduled-tasks

I am a newbie on task, parallel and scheduling etc. Here I created two blockingcollection. One is for collecting input, the other is for output. I added 100 items. So I think that the total counts of them should be 100 or 0. Or the sum of them is equal 100.

However I found that they are all 0. Please help me to understand these concepts using simple language.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().run();
    }
    void run()
    {
        int threadCount = 4;
        Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

        Task.Factory.StartNew(consumer);
        // We can do other work in parallel
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            int workerId = i;
            Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
            workers[i] = task;
            task.Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
            inputQueue.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
        inputQueue.CompleteAdding();
        Console.WriteLine("The count in InputQueue= {0}", inputQueue.Count);// 0
        Task.WaitAll(workers);
        outputQueue.CompleteAdding();
        Console.WriteLine("The count in OutputQueue= {0}", outputQueue.Count); // 0
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void worker(int workerId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

        foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
            Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
            outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
    }

    void consumer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer is starting.");

        foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Consumer is finished.");
    }

    BlockingCollection<int> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    BlockingCollection<int> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 3 stage pipeline

```
run -- (inputQueue) -- worker -- (outputQueue) -- consumer
```

all 3 stages run at the same time so as soon as 1 item is in `inputQueue` it can be immediately taken out and moved to `outputQueue`, as soon as one item is put in to `outputQueue` it can be immediately taken out and processed.

So to get a count of 100 you would need to do

```
(100 - number of items "run" has put in to "inputQueue") + 
"inputQueue.Count" + 
some number between 0 and "threadCount" representing items that have been taken out of "inputQueue" but have not yet been put in "outputQueue" +
"outputQueue.Count" + 
the number of items "consumer" has taken out of "outputQueue"
```

Beacuse your number of threads and waits are perfectly balanced for the load it is most likely the above fomula would be `0 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 96` with the last 4 elements waiting to be processed in `worker` with everything else already processed by `consumer`. If you did half the worker threads and made consumer take 4 times longer to process you would have numbers like `0 + 48 + 2 + 25 + 25` with 48 waiting to be processed by a worker, 2 being processed by a worker, 25 waiting to be processed by consumer, and 25 already processed by consumer.

Comment: --@Scott, it is a great help. How do you think all 3 stages run at the same time? Is it because of Task.Factory.StartNew()?

Comment: Each `Task` in your program represents a seperate `Thread` so you have 1 thread from `Task.Factory.StartNew`, `threadCount` threads from `task.Start()`, and the main program thread that is executing `run()`.

Comment: @Love Try a longer pause in `consumer` or less threads in `worker` and you will then have non 0 numbers. Right now your system is perfectly balanced so there are no choke-points in your pipeline,

Comment: @Love See my update with a more detailed explanation with a imbalanced system.

Comment: --@Scott, thanks. I have another question. Actually in my run() method there is a catch/finally block, inside finally block I will dispose all resources. However one resource is use in the method 'Consumer()', I found sometimes the thread jumps to the finally block thus throw an exception "object instance is not set to an object" while debug, how to reorganize the code structure to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a null reference exception. you can check for null fist `if(someObject != null) someObject.Dispose();`